# Migrate from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: python, django

How to set up a project to use HTTPS? What do I need?

I use Django 1.4.2

I added

```
#https
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

How to configure urls.py? Does anyone have a sample configuration?

Comment: Did you buy and install a certificate?

Answer (score 2):

After you have **bought** and **installed** a certificated there's three ways to redirect from http to https.

1. Proxy configuration. (Allow HTTPS only)
2. Create a http to https redirection in the server configuration file
3. Use Django middleware for this, e.g.: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/880/

Comment: There is no need to buy a certificate, unless you want to eliminate "Do You Trust This Certificate?" dialog boxes.  Anyone can self-sign a SSL Certificate.

Comment: @Hedde Do you have a sample configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help: https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver

This will give you the ability to accept HTTPS requests using only Django.